# i3 - binding to $mod release code

Tags: linux, arch-linux, i3

I am trying to create an effect with i3 and polybar to show the polybar tray whenever the `$mod` key is pressed, and hide it when `$mode` is released. I am using the [hideIt.sh](https://github.com/tadly/hideIt.sh) script to implement the window showing/hiding feature, and `bindcode` to bind the command in the `i3` configuration. With the following configuration:

```
bindcode 133 exec hideIt.sh --name '^polybar-bottom_eDP-1$' --toggle
bindcode --release 133 exec hideIt.sh --name '^polybar-bottom_eDP-1$' --toggle
```

The functionality only works if I press and release only the $mod key (in this case the Windows key code is 133). Now, if I press, for example, `$mod+2` to switch to my second workspace, the polybar is shown, but not hidden on release.

TL;DR is there any way to catch the `$mod` key release after a defined shortcut is pressed? Or, as a fallback, is there any way to bind to *any* key release event to hide the polybar after all keys are released? Thank you!

Comment: I'm using `xdotool` instead of the `hideIt` script but I'm having the same issue as you. Very annoying that you have to press the `$mod` key again for the polybar to go away

Answer (score 0):

There is a (closed) bug thread referencing `Super_L` (and `Alt_L`) and `--release` not working.

This (`bindcode --relase`, `bindsym --release`) works for most keys other than `Super_L`; e.g. `Caps_Lock` (code 66).  https://github.com/i3/i3/issues/2733#issuecomment-360442845

```
bindcode 66 exec notify-send "normal"
bindcode --release 66 exec notify-send "release"
```

The above configuration will issue notifications when caps lock is pressed and released, regardless if a key (like "a") is pressed or released alongside.